# "As Applicable" Concluding a Sentence

Tags: grammar, commas

I am a technical writer, and often I find concluding a list of requirements with "as applicable" is useful, because not all items in a list of requirements are relevant in all cases.

Consider a sentence such as:

> In your application, please include your telephone number, cell phone number, e-mail address, names of maiden aunts, and a list of schools you have attended.

It calls for an "as applicable" at the end because you may not have a maiden aunt, for instance.

Should the phrase be written as:

> ...schools you have attended, as applicable.

or

> ... schools you have attended as applicable.

The first has the comma after the list, the second does not.  My intuition says you should use the comma, but I cannot think of a reason why.  I would like a reason, so I can convince another writer that the comma should be there.

Comment: You intuition sounds reasonable. A comma indicates a pause in speech - that's all there is to it, really. If you were using *speech* to rattle off such a long list of requirements to someone, you'd obviously pause after the last actual requirement (if only for *breath!* :). So stick a comma in.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was going to say the same, but I really wanted to see if anyone could point to a grammatical reasoning for this.  The comma is after all the most dangerous weapon in the grammar arsenal!

Comment: @David: I have very little interest in grammarians telling me I must set parenthetical clauses off in commas, & such. So far as I'm concerned orthography is the poor relation of real language, which is spoken. If the spoken form *requires* a pause to disambiguate possible meanings (as it did in the last sentence), there *must* be a comma in the written form. In all other cases, commas are optional.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is why you and I agree so often.  But, I'm trying to become a better grammarian so that I will stop being yelled at by grammarians. ;)

Comment: @David: That's one way, I guess. Another is just yell back at them, only **LOUDER!**

Comment: @FumbleFingers HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA

Comment: I would go so far as to say that the comma there is mandatory. The expression *as applicable* qualifies the **list**, not the last word preceding it. That should be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The comma isn’t so much a dangerous weapon as an easily blunted scalpel.

Whatever pointing practice you follow, mechanical or rhetorical, using too many commas tends to blur the significance of each. So while FumbleFingers is exactly correct in suggesting that a comma before *as applicable* marks the natural pause you take in speech before adding this qualification to what has gone before, its significance is confused by the presence of all those other commas which serve a different purpose.

I suggest instead that a more readable solution would be to mark this phrase with different points—it might be parentheses, it might be dashes—and that you place the parenthesis *before* the list, to avoid distressing your readers by implying that their applications will be defective if they fail to include the names of maiden aunts they don’t have:

> In your application, please include (as applicable) your telephone number, cell phone number, e-mail address, names of maiden aunts, and a list of schools you have attended.

(And if it wuz me I’d do something to clarify the scope of that *your*, which at present gives the impression of including *(your) names...* and *(your) list...*, too. But once I start rewriting I find it hard to stop.)

Comment: Love it. Do you just effortlessly manage to write so much easily-parsed text with so few commas, or do you have to go back over it after writing, looking for surplus commas to expunge? I think I *always* use too many (and too many full stops where a comma would have been enough). It's a bad habit that's hard to break.

Comment: I, personally, try to use, as I see fit, as many commas as possible. :-)  Great answer!  I might even go so far as to suggest:  *In your application please include all that apply:*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, my besetting fault is semicolons. Commas are easy: commas are breaths, and as an ex-theatre guy (specifically, an ex-Shakespeare-and-Shaw guy), I'm used to thinking of a breath as 15-30 words rather than 4-5, because I *don't have to stop to make them up*.

Comment: @StoneyB So, it is more a matter of cardiovascular health than grammatical correctness?

Comment: @DavidM As long as you establish the habits early, they'll stick around after the cigarettes give you the hook.

Comment: Oh I *see!* - It's because you've got a well-developed "inner voice" that you can more easily "listen" to, to see where the pauses *have* to come, in *whole utterances*. I on the other hand have a rubbishy inner voice which only reads one or two words at a time. *And* keeps hamming it up and overstressing too many words, so my eventual text is clogged up with "scare quotes", *italics*, and **worse**!

Comment: @DavidM Joking aside, commas are usually needed for more than just breaths: they mark pitch and cadence as well. But most people use far more than they need.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm guilty of comma abuse.  I admit it and that's the first step.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's more like a inner editor who makes me rewrite and rewrite and rewrite to satisfy his sadistic whims.

Comment: @DavidM If it's anything like smoking it's probably the last step too. ... And I had a client complaining just this morning that my sentences were too long for his staff (all college graduates) to read.

Comment: @StoneyB: Your inner editor is to be commended, even if he *is* a hard taskmaster. I dunno the exact appropriate quote or who said it  - something along the lines of *"The trick is to make it **look** easy"*, regardless of how much effort it took to get there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The flip side is the actor's slogan: If you don't tell em you screwed up they'll never know.

Answer (score 1):

What FumbleFingers and StoneyB said.

But there is also a grammatical reason for the comma, if you place the *as applicable* at the end of the sentence. You have provided a list of possible answers, the last of which is *a list of schools*. Without a comma to set off *as applicable*, the delimiting phrase might be misconstrued to apply only to the last item list rather than the list entire.  While StoneyB's repositioning of the modifier is a more effective solution, the comma reduces the chance of confusion.